# Python ode first order, how to solve this using Sympy

Tags: ode

When I try to solve this first ode by using Sympy as it shows below:

```py
import sympy
y = sympy.Function('y')
t = sympy.Symbol('t')

ode = sympy.Eq(y(t).diff(t),(1/y(t))*sympy.sin(t))
sol = sympy.dsolve(ode,y(t))
csol=sol.subs([(t,0),(y(0),-4)]) # the I.C. is y(0) = 1
ode_sol= sol.subs([(csol.rhs,csol.lhs)])
print(sympy.pprint(ode_sol))
```

It gives me this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Mohammed Alotaibi/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/ODE2.py", line 26, in <module>
csol=sol.subs([(t,0),(y(0),-4)]) # the I.C. is y(0) = 1
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'subs'
```

Comment: You have not defined `y` and `t`.

Comment: I put that already, but I did not put it here , sorry y = sympy.Function('y')
t = sympy.Symbol('t')

Comment: Half of your code, tags, and title are not relevant to your problem at all. Please try to produce a [mcve] for your problem. Probably this will make you understand what your problem is. Reading and understanding that error message may also help. If all of this fails, [edit] your question with the remaining problem.

Comment: "Minimal" related to the unnecessary numpy and scipy imports. With your latest changes, your lines are even less runnable.

Comment: Lutzl, numpy and scipy will not affect on the code. My only problem as it shows in the error message that I cannot use "subs" to solve the constant! How can I solve this problem? I can get the ode solution, but the constant is unknown in this case!

Comment: Does your method work for an equation with a unique solution like `y'=y**2`?

Comment: Please show the code for `y` and `t` **in your question**, not in comments. Make the example as runnable as possible.

Comment: Without the missing variables to help future readers, this question is presently off-topic. I am voting to close for now, but very happy to reopen if it can be improved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that this ODE does not have a unique solution. Thus it returns a list of solution, which you can find out from the error message and by printing `sol`.

Do the evaluation in a loop,

```
for psol in sol:
    csol = psol.subs([(t,0),(y(0),-4)]);
    ode_sol = psol.subs([(csol.rhs,csol.lhs)]);
    print(sympy.pprint(ode_sol))
```

to find the next error, that substituting does not solve for the constant. What works is to define `C1=sympy.Symbol("C1")` and using

```
    ode_sol= psol.subs([(C1, sympy.solve(csol)[0])]);
```

but this still feels hacky. Or better to avoid error messages for the unsolvability of the second case:

```
C1=sympy.Symbol("C1");
for psol in sol:
    csol = psol.subs([(t,0),(y(0),-4)]);
    for cc1 in sympy.solve(csol):
        ode_sol= psol.subs([(C1, cc1)]);
        print(sympy.pprint(ode_sol))
```

Comment: I do appreciate you help, Thanks a lot.